# how to detect file encoding in flex / actionscript?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, file-io

is there method/algo to detect universal **file encodings** ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is a built-in way to do that using AS3. However, I've got some classes that will convert to/from Base64 and GZip. If that's of interest to you let me know and I'll post code.

-- David

Comment: This is not a reall answer. It would have been if the code was pasted.